# Passing numbers as parameters in URL in request: PHP

Tags: php, parameters, get

Can I pass numbers as parameters in URL?
I am trying to get the slug name as below,

```
$slug = $post->post_name;
$pagePath = site_url() . '/listing-details/?p=' . $slug;
```

and trying to get the slug as below,

```
$the_slug = $_GET['p'];
```

Now the issue here, in some cases I am getting the $slug value as something like

> 650-jefferson-ave

Thus finally my URL which I am getting, becomes:

> http://localhost/project/listing-details/?p=650-jefferson-ave

Thus in that case my $the_$slug is returning null and this url is redirecting the default http://localhost/project/listing-details/ page without any parameters.

How can I achieve this? Please anyone help.

Comment: You cant have another `$` in the variable name

Comment: @MarvinFischer That was a typo. Corrected now.

Comment: It looks like it's got the article/page ID prepended to it. You need to split it off, using explode `list($id, $slug) = explode('-', $_GET['p'], 2);`

Comment: @Geoffrey Actually my post name contains names starting with digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['email'];
```

and make sure you have a parameter `p` after your url

like

```
/post/?p=something
```

Comment: I am already doing this. The issue here is /post/?p=$slug is having numbers thus it is returning nothing.

Comment: This isn't working. Can u please have a look on the edited question? Maybe you can get an idea on what I mean.